# Information Retrival LLama-Index

Tags: python, large-language-model, llama-index

I am building a Name Entity Recognition system using llama-index and chatgpt api , i have build a template with chatgpt but i need to convert to llama-index template , What is procedure and how to build with llama-index ?

code build with chatgpt api :

```
def info_extraction_engine(file_path , api_key):

    def extract_text_from_pdf(pdf_path):
        text = ""
        pdf_reader = PyPDF2.PdfReader(pdf_path)
    
        for page in pdf_reader.pages:
            text += page.extract_text()
    
        return text

    # Replace 'your_pdf_file.pdf' with the path to your PDF file
    pdf_text = extract_text_from_pdf(file_path)
    
    openai.api_key = api_key
    
    SYSTEM_PROMPT = "You are a smart and intelligent Information Extraction system. I will provide you the definition of the entities you need to extract and the sentence from which you need to extract the entities and the output in given format with examples."

    USER_PROMPT_1 = "Are you clear about your role?"

    ASSISTANT_PROMPT_1 = "Sure, I'm ready to help you with your NER task. Please provide me with the necessary information to get started."

   
    PROMPT = (
    "Entity Definition:\n"
    "1. NAME: Short name or full name of a Person\n"
    "2. ADDRESS : some text.\n"

    "\n"
    "Output Format:\n"
    "{{'PROJECT_NAME': [list of entities present], 'ADDRESS': [list of entities present]}}\n"
    "If no entities are presented in any categories keep it None\n"
    "\n"
    "Example"
    "Output: {{'NAME': ['Khan'], 'ADDRESS': ['Spain']]}}\n"
    "\n"
    "3. Sentence: {}\n"
    "Output: "
    )

    
    def openai_information_extraction_response(final_prompt):
        response = openai.ChatCompletion.create(
                  model="gpt-3.5-turbo-16k",
                  messages=[
                        {"role": "system", "content": SYSTEM_PROMPT},
                        {"role": "user", "content": USER_PROMPT_1},
                        {"role": "assistant", "content": ASSISTANT_PROMPT_1},
                        {"role": "user", "content": final_prompt}
                    ]
                )

        return response['choices'][0]['message']['content']

    PROMPT = PROMPT.format(pdf_text)
    ners = openai_information_extraction_response(PROMPT)
    #return ners
    my_dict = ast.literal_eval(ners)
    porject_name = my_dict['NAME']
    fun_req = my_dict['ADDRESS']
    
    return porject_name , fun_req
```